# Read and write in a serial port using two different script

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, at-command

I am trying to handle a SIMCOM Modem (SIM7100E) over a serial port using AT command.
To do that, I am trying to build a script that will always listen to the serial port and handle answer like:

```
import serial

ser =serial.Serial('/dev/ATModem_SIM2',115200)
while True:
    line=ser.readline()
    print(line)
```

and using another script, I tried to send AT commands to the same serial port:

```
echo "AT" > /dev/ATModem_SIM2
```

while expecting to read OK in the python script, I read "AT\n" and not the answer!

Note: The Modem works fine and I already test it using [catty](https://sourceforge.net/projects/catty/) and I get the answer:

```
root@phyboard-mira-imx6-5:~# catty  -d /dev/ATModem_SIM2 -b 115200 -1 -8 -n -l -r 8 -s 10 -t 100 -x -w "AT\r"
AT
OK
root@phyboard-mira-imx6-5:~# catty  -d /dev/ATModem_SIM2 -b 115200 -1 -8 -n -l -r 8 -s 10 -t 100 -x -w "ATI\r"
ATI
Manfacturer: SIMCOM INCORPOATED
Revision: SIM7100E_V4.5
IMEISV: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
+GCAP: +CGSM

OK
```

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to do:
[image]

Comment: Just to understand: the problem occurs just when you use both your scripts _together_? What if you don't run the listening script and just use `cat /dev/ATModem_SIM2 & && echo "AT" > /dev/ATModem_SIM2 ` in the second one? I suspect concurrency issue in the serial port opening. What I don't understand is why you seem to be able to receive the echo of the command you gave (`AT\n`) and not the answer.

Comment: What you're trying to do makes no sense.  How does the listening script know what to expect?  If the modem responds with an error, how is the sending script notified?  The dialogue with the modem (in command mode) is a simple request-response exchange of messages.  There is no need for concurrent transmit & receive processes.  You're creating unneeded complexity and new problems.  What's the advantage of this scheme?

Comment: It's an experimental project with new releases stalled, but maybe pyserial-asyncio could be used. [pyserial-asyncio 0.4](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial-asyncio/) What if you take over and resume development?